# Removing query string from url in php

Tags: php, url

Lest say i have a link and when some one click on that link it redirect the person to the following page

```
http://localhost/install.php?act=go
```

now i just want to remove everything after ? so that person doesn't see the actual query string behind it or is there any way to encode the characters and make it look different in browser

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can only send GET parameters by appending to the URL.

Comment: i dnt want people to look at my parameters

Comment: If you don't want people to look at your parameters, try using session or cookie data to keep the state of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a mod_rewrite rule to your htaccess something like
 `RewriteRule ^install/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ /install.php?act=$1`
that way /install/go takes you to the destinantion

Comment: @Jonathan: Is this just an aesthetic issue, or should this info really not be visible to the user? Also, if you need more than one parameter, you'll need a different rewrite rule.

Comment: thing is that on one page i am performing more than one task after checking the $_GET values so if everyone is able to see those values than they will not follow the right steps and try to jump forward

Comment: If it's something like a multi-page form, can you just send the values via POST instead? Or would it be more appropriate to store them in the session where the user can't see/modify the value once it's been set?

Comment: using the rewrite above it accomadates for any value of act so if your next step was /install.php?act=something then you can point /install/something but yes if you want more that parameter then u will need a different rewrite or you can do as chris suggested and use a post or session

Comment: yeah post won't work in my case but using sessions will be good , i think guys u solved my problem ....Thanks to you ! :-)